# How to get new time in Java?

Tags: java, date, time

What is the correct way of getting the updated time in Java?

```
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    java.util.Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    String currTime = dateFormat.format(today);

    System.out.println(currTime);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000); 
        System.out.println("2s delayed"); //2000 milliseconds delay
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    System.out.println(currTime);
```

This will give me something like this:

```
2016/04/07 12:39:05.281

2s delayed

2016/04/07 12:39:05.281
```

*As you see it is the **same exact time**, even after the 2s delay.*

12:39:**07**.281 is the correct time for the second output.

Why am I not getting this?

Comment: You're only getting the current time once, formatting it into a string, and printing out the string twice. No matter how many times you print that string, or when, the same string is going to print. To get a new time, you have to request a new time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use a `Calendar` to get a `Date`? Just call `new Date()`.

Anyway, the main problem is that you are not getting an updated time before printing the second timestamp. When you call `new Date()`, you get the time as of the time of the call. To get a fresh timestamp, call `new Date()` again.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(new Date()));
try {
    Thread.sleep(2000); 
    System.out.println("2s delayed");
} catch(InterruptedException ex) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(new Date())); // different Date object to get fresh time
```

**OUTPUT**

```
2016/04/07 13:12:51.299
2s delayed
2016/04/07 13:12:53.299
```

Comment: This is good! But why do I get tiny errors like: Add arguments to match Date(long).. Date(int, int, int)...

Comment: @JDoe You accidentally imported `java.sql.Date`, not `java.util.Date`.

Answer (score 3):

Call [`now()`,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#now--) or—even better—[`now(Clock)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#now-java.time.Clock-) each time you want an update.

```
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");

System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now(clock).format(format));
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now(clock).format(format));
```

If the caller uses a `Clock` instance, more interesting unit tests are easy to write. A lot of time-sensitive code should be given the time to use; if it needs to get the time itself, it should use a `Clock` instance, which is probably injected at construction time.

I thought Andreas’ answer nicely illustrated the old way, but I wanted to make sure the current approach is presented too. Java 8 was the current version when the question and this answer were posted.

Comment: Silently switching to Java 8 time API. At least say that you do it, and that it's for Java 8 only. Not everybody on here are using Java 8 yet.

Comment: @Pillar Thanks! I never noticed that API.

Comment: @Andreas Java 8 is the current version. Updates for Java 7 ended a year ago. There is no reason to assume that a solution should be limited to Java 7 unless specifically requested.

Comment: Another great solution and creative variable name choice ;).

Comment: @erickson I wasn't saying that you shouldn't suggest Java 8, but given the number of people on here who are not yet on Java 8, at least say something, e.g. "You should use the new Java 8 time classes, since the old Date implementation is faulty", or "..., because it's so much easier to use than the old Date classes".

Comment: @Andreas I thought your answer nicely illustrated the old way, but I wanted to make sure the current approach is presented too.

Comment: It’s not for Java 8 only. It works nicely with the backport of java.time (AKA JSR-310) to Java 6 and 7, the [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), And indeed java.time is the recommended way. `SimpleDateFormat` is not only long outdated (typing in 2020), it was also always troublesome.

Answer (score 1):

Before doing the second `System.out.println(currTime)` you need to reset the value of your variable `currTime` as next:

```
today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
currTime = dateFormat.format(today);
System.out.println(currTime);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have an easier method of doing it.....

But it is a bit different to your code.....

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.TimeZone;
public class d_and_t
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc= new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the place for time... for ex... IST...");
        String a=sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("the time and date is   ........");
        SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd");
        System.out.println(dt.format(new Date()));
    }
}
```

Here you have the option to get time for whichever place you want...

BufferedReader method.......

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.io.*;
public class d_and_t
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc= new Scanner (System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter the place for time... for ex... IST...");
        try{
            String a=br.readLine();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("the time and date is   ........");
        SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd");
        System.out.println(dt.format(new Date()));
    }
}
```

Comment: It’s like it’s answering a different question? Also please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Answer (score 0):

A `calendar` object is not made for that, you can in fact set every second  the  new date/time over and over again, but as said this class is not made for this and is consider a bad practice... you should  use instead `System.currentMills` or create a new instance of the `Date` class.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have a clock. Your variable `today` is like a picture of that clock. You are looking at that picture after time has passed and you are seeing the old time. To see the current time you need to take a new picture of the clock. Get the time  again after the delay and format that.
`dateFormat.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());`

Comment: Calling `Calendar.getInstance()` does that. `new SimpleDateFormat()` does not capture a time at all, since it just creates a *formatter/parser*.

Comment: I realized that and changed my answer thanks :) sorry it took so long i could not format it right